# Specifying architecture in apt sources list

Tags: debian, apt

I had to add `i386` architecture to apt sources list to be able to install 32 bit package required for gaming.

My `sources.list` now look like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
    
deb https://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src https://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
        
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free contrib non-free-firmware
```

To install the package adding i386 was required only for first line, but I'm not sure if I should add the arch to all lines?

For instance if I don't does this mean that the package won't be updated when using apt update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On debian, if you have enabled multiarch using `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, you don't need to set the `arch=` in your `sources.list`.

[Setting up apt sources](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources). explained on Debian Wiki.

Comment: Yes I did `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, didn't know I don't need to add into `sources.list` as well, thanks.

Comment: But I would appreciate to know, if I didn't, would I need to modify all lines then?

Comment: @metablaster typically you need to use the architecture option in your sources if you want something other than what dpkg expects (e.g., only a specific architecture, or specific set of architectures, for a specific repo)

Comment: @metablaster I have added a link to the debian wiki.

Comment: I have read it, thanks! is also says `Arch-qualifying deb-src lines doesn't make any sense`, good to know!